# Angularjs Why I cannot directive scope variable "dataSource"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Noticed strange thing, when I name directive scope parameter `dataSource` it always `undefined`.

Here is an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/F0wIVUTj9lavVZyFIxKn?p=preview

If you change `dataSource` to for example `ds` everything works.

Question: why?

Comment: And are you sure to use exactly `scope: { dataSource: "="  }` instead of `scope: { dataSource: "&"  }`. controllerFunction is function not simple property. If you will change it dataSource will not be undefined [edited sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/WlkCPocePTxsDSUKeNl9?p=preview).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization), angular normalizes all attributes, a standard prefix for attributes is `data-`. So when you name your attribute `data-source`, it will actually be bound to your directive as `source`

Your corrected fiddle [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/JTFuJFt9PxZ3aXysD7yu?p=preview)

Now can be accessed as `$scope.source` in your directive.